# How do I show the Steps in a SpecFlow report using nunt 3?

Tags: bdd, specflow, nunit-3.0

The SpecFlow sample documentation has a `show` link next to the scenario which I assume shows the steps.
[image]
When I generate my report I don't have this link.
[image]

I runt the tests and generate the report as follows using Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Framework 4.6.2

> %solution_root%packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.6.1\tools\nunit3-console.exe
> --labels=All --out=output.txt "--result=output.xml;format=nunit2" SystemIntegration.Test.dll
>
> %solution_root%packages\SpecFlow.2.1.0\tools\specflow.exe
> nunitexecutionreport %project_file% /xmlTestResult:output.xml
> /testOutput:output.txt /out:report.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently the `output.txt`needs to be in the nunit2 format as well but `format=nunit2` does not work on that arg. To update the .txt file I added a powershell command to replace `=>` with `*****` in the output text file before running the execution report.

> powershell -command "(get-content 'output.txt') | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '=>', '*****' } | Set-Content 'output.txt'"

Note: this is fixed in SpecFlow code but not yet released.  Will update this answer when fix is available.